# jquery link dies after clicking

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

So for the most part my jquery works fine with the exception of the transition of my socbar when hidden and shown. Besides that, my biggest issue is that once my socbar is collapsed, the link to expand becomes dead until the page is refreshed. What's wrong with my code?

**My jscript:**

```
$(".socbar").hide().before("<div class='social_button'></div>");
$(".social_button").click(function(){
var $link = $(this);
$link.next().show("slow");
$link.remove();
return false;
});
$(".arrow").click(function(){
$(".socbar").hide().before("<div class='social_button'></div>");
return false;
});
```

**My Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>

 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

 <title>Test Page</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
 </head>



 <body>

<div class="container clearfix">

    <div class="navbar_container grid_5">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div class="nav_container grid_2 omega">
                <div class="socbar">
                    <ul class="soc">
                        <li><a href="#" id="Facebook" 
 title="Facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="Linkedin" 
 title="Linkedin"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="Youtube"  
 title="Youtube"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="arrow" title="Collapse">     
 </span>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#" id="Portfolio"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Services"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="About"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Home"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/nav.js"></script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

**Demo:**

http://testpage.aws.af.cm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've chosen to add and remove the .social_button element, you need to use event delegation to handle the click event.

Change:

```
$(".social_button").click(function(){
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click','.social_button',function () {
```

Comment: Works Perfect! May I ask for help with my weird transition? When collapsing and expanding, the bar scales its size. How can I expand it at full size?